# A uniform electric field $\bar{E}$ penetrates a surface having the shape of a cylinder of radius $R$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, gauss-law

A uniform electric field $\bar{E}$ penetrates a surface having the shape of a cylinder of radius $R$ cut in half. The field lines enter perpendicularly through the base which has a flat rectangular shape, length $L$ and width $2R$.
[image]

Calculate explicitly the electric field flow through the flat and curved surfaces of the semi-cylinder.

My attempt:

Let us first consider the two side covers of the cylinder. As the vector $\bar{E}$ is perpendicular to the normal vector of the two side covers then

$$\phi_1 = \phi_2 = 0$$

Let us now consider the rectangular lid. The normal vector to the surface and the electric field vector are anti parallel, therefore:

$$\phi_3 = \int_{S_3} \bar{E}~d\bar{A}_3 = \int_{S_3} E\cos\pi~dA = -2ELR $$

Now let's look at the flow in the cylindrical part. The normal vector forms an angle $\theta$ with respect to the vector $\bar{E}$, in this part, I'm stuck.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Why are you stuck? Do you understand what $d\vec A$ is for the cylindrical surface?

Comment: Are you familiar with Gauss' law? That will give you your answer.,

Comment: @BobD I think “calculate explicitly” means “do the surface integrals”.

Comment: @G.Smith Oops. Didn't see that.

Comment: @G.Smith I'm stuck in the integral $\int_{S_4} \bar{E}d\bar{A} = \int_{S_4} E\cos{\theta}dA$

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindrical_coordinate_system) for the element of area on a cylindrical surface.

Comment: @G.Smith i know that $\int_{S_4} ERL\cos{\theta}d\gamma$ How can I relate the $\cos{\theta}$ with $\gamma$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some nice symmetry here. Here is how I would set it up:

[image]

Note that the blue rectangle is your $dA$.

Answer to your comment:

[image]

Comment: Hello thanks for your answer. Then mi integral is : $\int_{S_4} \bar{E}d\bar{A} = \int_{S_4} E\cos{\gamma}dA = \int_{S_4} E\cos{\gamma}RLd\theta = ERL \int_{S_4} \cos{\gamma}d\theta$ where $\gamma$ is the angle of the vector $\bar{E}$ and the normal surface.  ? how can proceed after this?

Comment: in the drawing my $\theta$ is your $\gamma$. just integrate from $\theta_1=-\dfrac\pi2$ to $\theta_2=\dfrac\pi2$

Comment: the angle between $\mathrm d \bf \vec A$ and $\bf \vec E$ is $\theta$ (or $\gamma$, however you choose to call it)

Comment: I don't see why the angles are the same. Can you be more clear in that part please?

Comment: @Bvss12 i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks for all! Very clear

Comment: I cannot make sense out of this problem nor of its solution. In what external field do you immerse this half-cylinder object (presumably a dielectric) to arrive at the kind of uniform field distribution the picture shows?